# Canonical quantisation harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, harmonic-oscillator

I have a question on the canonical quantisation as described at the linked wiki page:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory#Canonical_quantisation

we take the displacement of a classical harmonic oscillator described as $$  x(t)={\frac {1}{\sqrt {2\omega }}}ae^{-i\omega t}+{\frac {1}{\sqrt {2\omega }}}a^{*}e^{i\omega t}, $$

and promote $x(t)$ to a linear operator ${\displaystyle {\hat {x}}(t)}$:

$${\displaystyle {\hat {x}}(t)={\frac {1}{\sqrt {2\omega }}}{\hat {a}}e^{-i\omega t}+{\frac {1}{\sqrt {2\omega }}}{\hat {a}}^{\dagger }e^{i\omega t}.}$$

the coefficients $a$ and it's complex conjugate $a^*$ are replaced ${\hat  a}$ and ${\hat  a}^{\dagger }$.

Question: why following this instruction ${\hat  a}$ becomes creation operator and ${\hat  a}^{\dagger }$ annihilation opererator and not conversely? is there any physical reason that justifies it based on the plus or minus sign of $e^{-i\omega t}$ resp. $e^{i\omega t}$? or is it just a "random choice"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In quantum mechanics, $a$ and $a^\dagger$ are *ladder operators*, in that they raise and lower the number of excitations presence in the harmonic oscillator:
  $$ a^\dagger |0\rangle \propto |1\rangle \quad \Rightarrow \quad a^\dagger |n\rangle = \sqrt{n+1}|n+1\rangle, \\
  a|1\rangle \propto |0\rangle \quad \Rightarrow \quad a|n\rangle = \sqrt{n}|n-1\rangle.$$

  Each application on $a$ on your number-eigenstate $|n\rangle$ *removes* a quantum of excitation ($\hbar \omega$ for the harmonic oscillator). The opposite for $a^\dagger$.

  $a^\ast$ is the specific case of $a^\dagger$ when $a$ is a scalar, not a matrix.

  In field theory now, the vacuum $|0\rangle$ has no field excitations (i.e. no particles, no waves on the string). I can create one excitation by applying $a^\dagger$, like before. Since in the field theory context I am now *creating* a particle, it's called the *creation operator*. Same reasoning for the *annihilation operator* $a$.
- In the Heisenberg picture, the time dependence of an operator is given by:
  $$ \dot{A} = \frac{i}{\hbar} [H,A],$$
  so:
  $$ \dot{a} = \frac{i}{\hbar}[H, a] = \frac{i}{\hbar}[\hbar \omega \, a^\dagger a,a] = -\mathrm{i}\omega a \quad \Rightarrow \quad a(t) = a(0)e^{-\mathrm{i}\omega t},$$
  and

$$ \dot{a^\dagger} = \frac{i}{\hbar}[H, a^\dagger] = \frac{i}{\hbar}[\hbar \omega \, a^\dagger a,a^\dagger] = \mathrm{i}\omega a^\dagger \quad \Rightarrow \quad a^\dagger(t) = a^\dagger(0)e^{\mathrm{i}\omega t}.$$

Comment: morally you use the notation $x(t)={\frac {1}{\sqrt {2\omega }}}a(t)+{\frac {1}{\sqrt {2\omega }}}a^{*}(t)$ at first without knowing which exponential $e^{-i\omega t}$ or $e^{i\omega t}$ belong to which coefficient and deduce it by applying  derivatives at the equation with commutator from Heisenberg picture?

does this association creation operator -> $e^{-i\omega t}$ & annihilation operator -> $e^{i\omega t}$ have an "intuitive" meaning?

Comment: You first start with defining $a$ and $a^\dagger$ in terms of $x$ and $p$, all in time-independent formalism. The you compute the time dependence of the operators with the Heisenberg equation of motion (the commutator thing). If you want an intuitive meaning, the energy associated with a state after applying $a$ is $-\hbar \omega$ (since I can write $-\omega$ in the exponent as $E/\hbar$, because you are *removing* a quantum of energy $\hbar \omega$.

Comment: thinking about the *intuitive meaning* you explained I'm not sure if I understand you completely. let consider the case of annihilation operator $\hat {a}$: let $|n\rangle$ our initial state and it becomes $\sqrt{n}|n-1\rangle$. can I see the belonging coefficient $e^{-i\omega t}=e^{-iE/ \hbar t}$ as "energy portion that leaves the system" after applying the annihilation? heuristically justified by energy conservation? or have I misunderstood you?

Comment: My way was just a hand wavy way of remembering which operator has the $-\omega$. An energy eigenstate has a time dependence $\exp(iE/\hbar)$, so you act with $a$ it now becomes $E-\hbar\omega$ in the exponent.